# Display MVC View in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, webforms

I have an old website running Active Server Page Extended pages (aspx) and I want to add an iframe linked to an existing MVC .net application view.

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:443/MyController/Index" ></iframe>
```

But I get the error "localhost refused to connect".

The root of the MVC application displays fine.

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:443/" ></iframe>
```

How can I display other views?

Comment: Classic ASP files have the extension .asp, not .aspx which is for ASP.net webforms.  Is the url of the parent page https?  If it is then you may have problems using a plain http url in an iframe.  That said it sounds more like a server configuration issue than a coding issue

Comment: Thanks for the differentiation. I've updated the question and will look into server configurations that may help. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Event Viewer is often a good place to look for clues